# How to add a UILabel to UIToolbar?

Tags: ios, swift, uitoolbar

I've been trying to replicate Snapchat's blue pop-up rectangle prompt at the bottom on the "Send To..." page via 1) an IB `UIToolbar` with a `UILabel` for displaying text, and 2) programmatically via a `UIToolbar(frame: CGRectMake(x,y,width,height))`. In interface builder, I can't drag a label atop a toolbar, and I've been struggling with the programmatic route.

What's the best way to replicate the formatting of that toolbar in Swift? My view controller will be very similar to Snapchat's. Click someone's name and the toolbar appears animatedly from the bottom, with the recipients' array displayed on the toolbar.

I'd post a picture of the Snapchat example but I'm new to S.O and don't have the rep yet. :/ Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Here's a link to what I'm referring to. The blue send prompt at the very bottom. It appears only when 1 or more users are selected. [image: screenshot]

Comment: share your expected output screenshots.

Comment: Thanks @sasquatch. I don't even have enough reputation to post screenshots.

Comment: if my answer helps you please mark it as a accepted.

Comment: I used a much simpler method. And I asked for it in Swift. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Thanks for reply but i am was trying to help you. if you got better method no problem.

Comment: Doing this is not good.

Answer (score -1):

Try this to Show label on ToolBar.

```
NSMutableArray *items = [[self.toolbar items] mutableCopy];

UIBarButtonItem *spacer = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
[items addObject:spacer];


self.titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0 , 11.0f, self.view.frame.size.width, 21.0f)];
[self.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:18]];
[self.titleLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[self.titleLabel setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:157.0/255.0 green:157.0/255.0 blue:157.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
[self.titleLabel setText:@"Title"];
[self.titleLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];

UIBarButtonItem *spacer2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
[items addObject:spacer2];


UIBarButtonItem *title = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]    initWithCustomView:self.titleLabel];
[items addObject:title];

[self.toolbar setItems:items animated:YES];
```

OR

use it...

```
UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
[self.view addSubview:toolbar];

UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 44)];
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

UIBarButtonItem *item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:label];
toolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObject:item];

label.text = @"Hello World";
```